# $(...).ajaxForm is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

I load jquery and ajaxform plugin and after that init ajaxform on element.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js" /></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.form').ajaxForm();
});
```

Error: `$(...).ajaxForm is not a function`. 
It appears on [this site](http://u.to/BvHiDQ).

Answer (score 3):

Github isn't a CDN and will block you trying to use it as such.

`jquery.form.js` is available on numerous proper CDN's or you can download it and serve from your own site

Comment: I upload it on my server but there is no effect.

Comment: did you change the `src` in script tag to point to new location? Is file loading in dev tools network?

Comment: of course, I changed src and i see it loaded in firebug

Comment: You have full copy of jQuery 1.9.1 in your `all.js`. It loads after plugin and wipes out whole jQuery object loaded by jquery.js which is version `1.11.2`. Easy way to verify this is `console.log($.fn.jquery)//1.9.1`

Comment: So basically you have 2 versions of jQuery library being loaded

Comment: I load ajaxform with `$.getScript(...)` before init, but now I have other error: `this.elem is null` in `if (this.clonedElem = this.elem.cloneNode(!0), this.clonedElem.className += " " ...` on line 3921.

Comment: why not just remove jQuery 1.9 from `all.js`? Pretty simple to write your own ajax instead of use `ajaxForm`. That's  really old plugin and isn't needed much any more in modern browsers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102863/discussion-between-artem-and-charlietfl).